# not able to send any request with HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I'm trying to send a request with `HttpClient` using `IHttpClientFactory` on `.net core 2.2` but I get an `HttpRequestException` and a `SocketException` as following:

`A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

I tried increasing client timeout, and keeping alive connection, but no luck.
Also I've found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/36221) issue that is still open, but I'm not sure if my problem is the same with that or not, because I don't have any high load on this local server.

```
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");

    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("client");
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = false;

    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

and in my `Startup.cs` I have:

```
services.AddHttpClient("client");
```

Comment: Can you post your implementation of the IHttpClientFactory interface? Also, is this inside an ASP.NET Project?

Comment: Do you get this exception every time? Then you probably need to configure a firewall or proxy server to allow this app for outgoing requests.

Comment: @MindSwipe I believe IHttpClientFactory interface is part of the Microsoft.Extensions.Http. Also if there is a chance of the endpoint you are trying to reach to block it.

Comment: @MindSwipe I don't have any implementation for IHttpClientFactory. That line in startup injects it into my class, I believe. This is a .net core 2.2 web api project.

Comment: @CodeCaster It was fine until yesterday. And I didn't do anything, just ran my tests and saw every api call is failing.

Comment: @Dimitar Endpoint are ok, as you can see, I'm using test apis, the same request works just fine on postman

Comment: @Dimitar IHttpClientFactory is part of the System.Net.Http namespace and is an Interface, and because we don't have default implementation in interfaces ([yet](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/default-implementations-in-interfaces/)) there is no way for us too know how he is constructing his HttpClient

Comment: @MindSwipe I can't aggree with "way to find what is the default implementation". Since .Net Core is open source and it's source code is in github - you can just check the implementation of the AddHttpClient extension method and dig a bit. (For example: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/11cf90103841c35cbefe9afb8e5bf9fee696dd17/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs).

Comment: @Dimitar you're right. After some further investigation I found the [DefaultHttpClientFactory](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/11cf90103841c35cbefe9afb8e5bf9fee696dd17/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs) which seems to be what OP is using

Comment: This is definitely firewall problem. I now can't even browse nuget packages.